# Curl Web Scraper Problems, wrong Array

Tags: php, post, curl, while-loop, screen-scraping

i have Problem with my Scraping Script. I like to select the value from my sql by id in a while and save the the scraped content in my database. its works but the curl script send a wrong result to my database, everytime the content from the first request.

My Code:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('db.php');

$i = 1;

while ($i <= 5)
{

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `plz` WHERE `id` = '$i'";
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query($sql) );

$plz = $row['plz'];


//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['adv_plz'] = "$plz";
$post_data['finda'] = 'adv';
$post_data['lang'] = 'de_DE';

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init('https://www.domain.de/');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
$result = utf8_encode($result);

mysql_query("UPDATE plz SET content = '$result' WHERE id = '$i'");


    $i++;
}


?>
```

Here is the Content of the echo $post_string

```html
adv_plz=01000&finda=adv&lang=de_DE

adv_plz=01000&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01001&finda=adv&lang=de_DE

adv_plz=01000&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01001&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01002&finda=adv&lang=de_DE

adv_plz=01000&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01001&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01002&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01003&finda=adv&lang=de_DE

adv_plz=01000&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01001&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01002&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01003&finda=adv&lang=de_DE&adv_plz=01004&finda=adv&lang=de_DE
```

I hope somebody can help me. If i try the script not in a while it works perfectly.

Comment: this one will do that http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2015/11/01/a-highly-flexible-php-web-crawler-library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting the $post_items variable before entering the foreach loop.

```
$post_items = array();

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_d ....
```